# How to establish a websocket connection from a Twilio webhook?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, websocket, twilio

I am trying to create a chat messaging application, which has text functionality. Right now, when a user sends an SMS message from their phone to a Twilio service number, there is a Twilio webhook which redirects to an endpoint in my backend server: sending HTTP POST request.

However, since it is a chat messaging application, I need the Twilio webhook to establish a Websocket connection (upgrading over HTTP) to my backend server, so that it can send websocket events back to my client.

Is there a way to establish a websocket connection using Twilio webhooks, or even Twilio functions? I can't find any resources online to solve this issue.

I tried Twilio Webhooks, and Twilio Functions, it hasn't worked so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets won't help you in this situation, as the webhook [timeout limit is 15 seconds](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-connection-overrides). This means you either need to return a TwiML response within 15 seconds or the request will fail.

It sounds like you want to build a stateful WebSocket connection instead of the stateless API callback. To achieve a stateful session, you either need to handle the state management over multiple incoming messages on your own, or you can use a Studio Flow which comes with state management baked in.

Comment: Please refrain from answer low-quality questions like this. Your answer could have been left as a comment instead. In this way you're still helping the asker, but also allowing the site cleanup tools to do their job.

Comment: He must have tried all online sources and could be newbee wanted some help.posting experimental code will again people to shout.If you have created such app please do share link, even i stuck there.so far referring https://www.twilio.com/blog/sms-spring-boot-app